# App crashes when dismiss mail composer and show a HUD

Tags: iphone, ios5, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, mbprogresshud

I have a button in my app, when press it, a MFMailComposerViewController will show up, and when the composer dismisses, a MBProgressHUD with a custom view will show to tell user whether the mail is sent successfully or not.

It works fine if I press send button in the composer, the mail will be sent, the composer will be dismissed and a HUD will show. However, if I press the cancel button in the composer view, the composer dismisses, but HUD doesn't show, and the app crashes.

Here are the Log of crash.

```
2012-02-02 22:49:34.821 App[5091:707] -[ViewController size]: unrecognized selector 
sent to instance 0x319210
2012-02-02 22:49:34.831 App[5091:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x319210'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x340af8bf 0x342ff1e5 0x340b2acb 0x340b1945 0x340b27b8 
0x3748cfa5 0xf051 0x203d1 0x37553f5b 0x374f393b 0x374f37bf 
0x3746d81b 0x37472fb9 0x34bc4ba7 0x36ce3e8d 0x340822dd 
0x340054dd 0x340053a5 0x30889fcd 0x37486743 0xe7a7 0xe74c)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

The `ViewController` is the controller that present the mail composer.

Here are some code I used:

```
-(void)showHUDWithMessage:(NSString *)msg
{
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc]initWithWindow:self.window];
[self.window addSubview:HUD];
HUD.delegate = self;
UIImage *image;
NSString *labelTextToShow;

//Do something here

UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image]autorelease];

HUD.labelText = labelTextToShow;
HUD.customView = imageView;

HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
[HUD show:YES];
[HUD hide:YES afterDelay:3.0];
}

-(void)mailFriend:(id)sender
{
MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[mailController setSubject:@"Mail Subject"];

NSString *emailBody = @"Message";
[mailController setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];

[self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];
}

-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller 
    didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
NSString *msg;
switch (result) {
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        msg = @"Sent";
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        msg = @"Fail";
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        msg = @"Cancelled";
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        msg = @"Cancelled";
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

//Show HUD here
[self showHUDWithMessage:msg];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[controller release];

}
```

Since if the mail is sent, the composer view can dismiss successfully, the HUD can also show correctly, I really don't know what's wrong here...

Thanks!

Comment: Something is sending the [size] message to a viewController.  I'll bet MBProgressHUD has a bug somewhere.  Hit Cmd+Shift+F and search for 'size'. There will most likely lie your problem.

Comment: @CodaFi I did think this might be the problem, but I can't find a method called "size"...

Comment: Try calling the method on a delay.  So, like [self performselector:@selector(callHUD) withObject:self afterDelay://time];

Comment: I'm sorry, try to change [self.window addsubview] to [self.view addSubview]

Comment: @CodaFi I tried this, still crashes...

Comment: Over-releasing object or accessing released object can cause similar crashes. UIKit might be doing something with your ViewController by sending size message, which might have been deallocated by the time message has been sent. Enable NSZombie environment variable and test your app.

Comment: @Jing look at the answer I have posted.

Comment: Are you trying to call any method using MBProgressHUD or just showing HUD?

Comment: Are you trying to call any method using MBProgressHUD or just showing HUD?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is overreleasing memory issue. Enable NSZombie and test your app.

Couple of things:
Where have you created controller ? You are responsible to release objects that you own. You don't own controller object so don't release it:

```
[controller release]; // comment this line
```

in
`-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller 
        didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error`

*Next*:

```
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller 
    didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
NSString *msg = nil; // If result is not equal to any of the case statements then you want to pass nil to [self showHUDWithMessage:msg];
switch (result) {
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        msg = @"Sent";
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        msg = @"Fail";
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        msg = @"Cancelled";
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        msg = @"Cancelled";
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

//Show HUD here
[self showHUDWithMessage:msg];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[controller release];

}
```

and `MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];` in `-(void)mailFriend:(id)sender` autorelease or release it later. Although this has nothing to do with issue you might have.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all reference to MBProgressHUD and put a simple NSLog in your method.  I'll bet my bottom dollar MB is causing this.

If not, memory management is my obvious second choice here.  Comment out [controller release];